# Xamarin Forms 4.0 Shell Flyout Menu Top part background color setting

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms, flyout

I am using Xamarin Forms 4.0 Shell to create an application. But I am unable to customize the very top part of the flyout menu to be black in color. I know setting the flyout background color to be black will solve that but I need to keep the lower part of the flyout to be other color. Is there any other way to achieve this? Please see the below image for reference.

[image: iOS iPhone XR Simulator Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

---

I have tried change UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle from Light to Default, the below screenshot shows that the clock shows with black font color (blue arrow), but the Wifi battery icon disappear (red arrow)

[image: iOS iPhone XR Simulator Screenshot]

---

Added [sample on Github](https://github.com/ltin071/XFSample20190702) for review.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I just ran across this issue myself. It would appear to be a bug actually. I posted up some of what I found over on your GitHub issue, where hopefully the Xamarin team will make a fix.

In the mean time, I found a workaround that makes the flyout header identical between all platforms without having to any weird other hacks.

For full reference - what I found is that the white bar above your flyout header is actually a part of the flyout content below - the menu items. If you change the background color of the flyout menu, you'll see for yourself. It would appear that the flyout menu is allowed to flow in to the iOS safe area, but the header cannot. What I did was used a negative margin in the layout of the flyout header template, then set some padding to offset the safe area in an onplatform block. Because this then effectively shrinks the content area, I set the height by platform as well. This ends up looking like the code below:

```
    <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Primary}">
                <StackLayout.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,-1,0,0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </StackLayout.Margin>
                <StackLayout.Padding>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </StackLayout.Padding>
                <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="220" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="200" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </StackLayout.HeightRequest>

                <ContentHere>...</ContentHere>

            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

I can't believe that I've only seen this issue posted here and in that GitHub link... but hopefully this helps out anybody else that runs in to this until a fix from the Xamarin team can go in to effect!

Comment: As a side note - the value of 20 for the padding is purely empirical. I have no idea if the safe area is actually 20px, or if this just happens to work out alright. I'd recommend testing this out for yourself before putting it in to play in production.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and create a Flyout Header control? With this control you can customize the upper section of the flyout. [Shell Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout)

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The black part with the profile picture with name and title thing is actually a Flyout Header control. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The very top part of the flyout menu in your picture is the **status bar**.

You seems set the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;`  in your project and the text color is `white`, so you won't see any text under a `white` background view.

To change the background color of status bar, you can set  `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default;` to make the status bar visible or custom the background color of status bar.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have edit the question to show the result for changing UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle from light to default. That doesn't seems achieve what I want. I am planning to white label my app and post it on Git for everyone to check. Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelLeung Yes, the wifi battery icon won't show as the width of flyout is short than the width of screen. BTW, where is the Git link.

Comment: Sorry just need some time to try white label as much as I can, the link is https://github.com/ltin071/XFSample20190702

Comment: Yeah, if you set the UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle to default, the wifi and battery turns to black style and they will not be visiable under a black background color.

Comment: I would like to explore any possibility to customize black status bar background with white time display when the flyout is opened, just need to be consistent with the appearance that the flyout is closed

Comment: If you find any solution, you can update here. I will also try to try to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am still looking into it. Will let you know if there's any update.

Comment: It's an interesting question only happens when you set the background color Black as under the default StatusBarStyle, the text color is black too. You can send your feedback in [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3Ajassmith) or [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Ok, follow the issue and you will get support there.

Comment: Thanks Jack, they have verified the issue and ready for work :)